# Bunch of SAS disk and want to wipe all of them

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, sas

I have 40 SAS disks. The model number is HUS156060VLS600. 600 GB 15K 3.5 inch SAS disk. It came from a customer. And the customer wants to wipe all data inside of SAS disks. Customer said the disk was spinning and transferring the data on the enclosure. At this point everything is okay.

Firstly I bought a SAS-to-SATA converter [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNGnS.png)
I had a Dell Server with a RAID card but only SATA ports. So I use the converter at this point. The Disk was not spinning.

I had another server HPE with a RAID card. I did the same things on the HPE server and disk spinning but not displayed on the BIOS.
After this I decided to use a Precision 7920T workstation with an SAS array. 4 pieces of SAS port in SAS Bay. I did too many combinations with all disks and ports. Again, disks are not spinning. I surfed and blocked the signal of pin 3 on the SAS disk with a kapton tape. Not working either.

Answer (score 1):

You need a SAS HBA. Then use sg_sanitize from sg3_utils package.
Examples:

Simple erase:

```
sg_sanitize --block /dev/sdX
```

Overwrite with given pattern:

```
sg_sanitize --overwrite --pattern=rand.img /dev/sdX
```

If you only have a RAID controller, than you can create a RAID volume and just fill it with zeroes or some random pattern (see [scrub](https://github.com/chaos/scrub)).

Answer (score 0):

Disks won't show up in the BIOS when connected through the RAID card. They are only accessible by the RAID itself. It manages them, assembles into arrays, creates virtual disks (VDs) on these arrays and presents those virtual disks to the OS and the BIOS.

To manage disks with RAID card you use the card BIOS utility or specialized OS software, for HPE servers this is usually SSA (Smart Storage Administration). I use CLI variant in Linux, so the exact package and executable is called `ssacli` in my case (it once called `hpssacli` and the ancient versions were called `hpacucli`, ACU stands for "array control utility"). But those HPE RAIDs don't allow to set up direct access to disks. Some RAID cards can erase disks for you, but I don't know which one do you have and how to instruct them to do so; learn which exactly card you have and read manual for your management software on how to do that.

To properly have a direct access to a disk from the OS you need either a HBA card, a RAID card flashed in HBA mode, or a RAID card which allows setting up JBOD access mode on the fly. In either case you can have a direct access to the disk from the OS and then erase it with e.g. `dd`. I had some success with that with LSI (then Avago, now Broadcom) MegaRAID. But not every LSI card firmware allows to do that; modern Dell PERC's are rebranded LSIs, but those I've had my hands on have a JBOD feature disabled. Again, I use them in Linux, and via CLI, so the package and executable I use is `megacli`. It has a successor, `storcli`, which I suppose must be better to use with recent Broadcom LSI-derived cards and/or older cards with updated firmware. I didn't used it myself.

Comment: `megacli` was replaced by `storcli` around the time that Broadcom bought LSI.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, thanks for noticing. I forgot about storcli. Added a note.